# How to repack a jar file with same manifest it had before?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I unzip a jar file, add a `filex` then zip it with this `filex` using the following command:

```
jar cf jarfile input-files filex META-INF
```

I figure out that after packing the `jar` with this new file the new `MANIFEST` is the default one which is basically empty:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

I would like to know if there is a flag to specify the `MANIFEST` while packing the jar again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html), a command of the form:

```
$ jar cmf existing-manifest jar-file input-file(s)
```

will let you include an existing manifest file.

Because jars are also zip archives, if all you want to do is to add `filex` to `jarfile`, you can also use:

```
$ zip jarfile filex
```

Also worth mentioning, if the file is [signed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html), you'll be breaking the signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify it with:

```
$ jar cmf existing-manifest jar-file input-file(s)
```

Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) for more info.

You can also put the default manifest and then modify it with:

```
jar cfm jar-file manifest-addition input-file(s)
```

Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) for more info on modification.

Answer (score -1):

Also it is possible, instead of repacking, to use directory, containing modified unpacked jar contents, with the same name the jar file had.